# Spree, Rails LineItems get only those that belongs_to completed Order

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, spree

I am trying to search for all LineItems that Order is completed.

```
# /spree/order.rb

def self.complete
  where.not(completed_at: nil)
end
```

I tried:

```
product.orders.complete.map { |o| o.line_items }.flatten
```

but it returns an Array and I can't do `.where(variant_id: ID)`.

or:

```
product.orders.includes(:line_items).complete.where(line_items: { variant_id: 263})
```

but it says: `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "line_items"`

Then I tried with:

```
product.line_items.includes(:order).where(variant_id: ID).where.not(order: { completed_at: nil })
```

and it returns `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'orders' was not found on Spree::LineItem; perhaps you misspelled it?`

This way is ok too: `product.orders.complete ...` but don't know how to search for LineItems by its variant_id.

How can I solve it? How can I return all Product's LineItems that belongs to completed Order?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ahh. Ok, figured out.

Finally solved it with this, notice I changed table name from `orders` to `spree_orders`:

```
product.line_items.joins(:order).where.not(spree_orders: { completed_at: nil })
```

And, can be done with `.includes(:order)` but it seems to make longer query and takes a little bit longer than `.joins(:order)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easily this way:

```
  # in Order Model (order.rb)
  scope :completed, -> { where.not(completed_at: nil) }

  # in Product Model (product.rb)
  has_many :orders
  delegate :completed, to: :orders, prefix: true
```

Now, you will be able to call `orders_completed` on a `product`:

```
product.orders_completed
```

and, then you can chain any where with this:

```
product.orders_completed.where(...)
```

Comment: Thanks man, will try it in a while, might be faster than my solution.